# Compress text file (CSV data) using LZ4 and read it in Spark

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lz4

I was using the linux command line lz4 to compress the csv file.

example:-

lz4 input.csv

which results in input.csv.lz4 as output

But when I try to read the lz4 file in spark shell using following commands it always results in empty result.

val output = sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").load("s3:///input.csv.lz4")

output.count
res: Long = 0

I found somewhere that lz4 commandline tool might incompatible with spark

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/7957/how-can-i-read-in-lz4-compressed-json-files.html

Has anyone got it working on reading lz4 files in spark. If yes how was lz4 file created ?